# Gear to gear connection (Please read the full description first)

Tags: openshift

I have checked almost all solutions both in Openshift forum and here in stackoverflow but couldn't solve the problem.

Here is the situation
I have a php server with load balancing in one gear.
I have a second gear for mysql server along with PhpMyAdmin. At present OpenShift does not support load balancing for PhpMyAdmin, so my second gear does not have any scaling feature.

Now I want to host a php app in first gear and the database in the second gear. So how do I connect them internally (would be better if I could do it without port forwarding)? I need all the commands from the beginning to the end unfortunately.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the mysql cartridge to your scaled application.  It will still put the mysql database on it's own gear, but it will be accessible from your scaled application using the standard mysql environment variables.  You can view those variables by sshing into your application and running `env | grep mysql`.  If you decide to run your own second gear for the mysql database (you still had to install a web cartridge anyways to do that right?) then you will either HAVE to use port forwarding for direct access, or you will have to write an API on that server that will allow your application to access the mysql database.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion which I've tried already. Here the problem is that though I can add mysql to my first gear, I cannot add Phpmyadmin as this gear has a load balancer. And without Phpmyadmin, updating database via ssh is extremely time consuming... One thing that can solve this problem is using my gear without any load balancer :(

Comment: Another thing, I've read in their forums that at present they do not allow port forwarding on a non-scaled gear, is it still the same? Cause my sql server is non-scaled.

Comment: If you are running a php application, why not just download the phpmyadmin code from phpmyadmin.net and add it to your project and run your own?  it is very easy to configure, just use the values of your environment variables.

Comment: Ahh great! Openshift doesn't allow to add phpmyadmin using command but I finally managed to do it manually :)